# oppo phone does not show allow usb debugging mode rsa authentication popup in windows

Tags: android, usb, adb

Oppo phone does not show allow usb debugging mode rsa authentication popup in windows. I have oppo A5S phone. USB debugging is on. and i tested with MTP/PTP mode. when i connect this phone with mac, it show "allow usb debugging popup, remember this phone with rsa but when i connect same phone in windows, it does not show the popup".  Can someone help. I already check so many post as stackoverflow/youtube and many blogs but none solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

I installed google USB driver, OEM drivers. I am able to see the phone name in device manager--opther device option and adb interface as well. One thing i notice adb interface has yellow icon. I have tried enabling/disabling usb debugging option and tried adb kill/start server/devices command. it show list of devices attached output and no device name.

adb devices should show device name. device should be listed in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution to this issue. right click to Adb interface and point to the already installed adb driver in your system. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for it just install a oppo pc suite in computer and . goto developer mode turn on usb debugging. There you are it will prompt a rsa ker verification thats all now you are connected. It worked for my oppo realme1.